# Fire alerts during gesture not after

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get these alerts to fire during the gesture, not after the gesture ends. So during the pinch gesture while the scale is 0.5 or less or while the scale is bigger than 1.0.

Hammer.js: http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/

Here is my code so far:

```
var hammertime = Hammer(document.body, {
       transform_always_block: true,
       transform_min_scale: 0,
       drag_block_horizontal: true,
       drag_block_vertical: true,
       drag_min_distance: 0
});

var posX = 0,
    posY = 0,
    lastPosX = 0,
    lastPosY = 0,
    bufferX = 0,
    bufferY = 0,
    scale = 1,
    last_scale,
    rotation = 1,
    last_rotation,
    dragReady = 0;

hammertime.on('touch drag dragend transform transformend', function(ev) {

    if ((" " + ev.target.className + " ").indexOf(" dataCard ") < 0) return;
    else manageMultitouch(ev, ev.target);

});

function manageMultitouch(ev, element) {

     switch (ev.type) { 
        case 'touch': last_scale = scale;
                last_rotation = rotation;
                return;
        case 'dragend':
                lastPosX = posX; 
                lastPosY = posY; 
                return; 
        case 'drag':
               posX = ev.gesture.deltaX + lastPosX;
               posY = ev.gesture.deltaY + lastPosY; 
               break; 
        case 'transform':
               rotation = last_rotation + ev.gesture.rotation;
               scale = Math.min(last_scale * ev.gesture.scale, 10);
               break;
     }

     if(scale <= 0.5) alert("scale is less than or equal to 0.5");

     if(scale > 1.0 ) alert("scale is bigger than 1.0");

     var transform = "translate(" + 0 + "px," + 0 + "px) " + "scale(" + 0 + "," + scale + ")"; 
     var style = element.style;
     style.transform = transform;
     style.oTransform = transform;
     style.msTransform = transform;
     style.mozTransform = transform;
     style.webkitTransform = transform;
  }
```

Comment: can you please make your code readable?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Okay, I made it more readable.

Comment: Ok, now imagine you know nothing about what you're trying to build (imagine *us*), now, read the question again.

Comment: Can you make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) wich passes JSHint validation?

Comment: @gomangomango no, I did :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thank you. Do you have any ideas on how to solve the issue?

Comment: @gomangomango don't use `alert()` to test but `console.log()` will get you more accurate data without breaking the gesture event.

Comment: Looking at your code but still I cannot figure out without additional notes (**or an example**) what could it possibly be... :|

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It is a pinch to transform gesture. Where the element the gesture is happening on becomes the height of the distance between the two fingers. I want an alert to fire DURING the gesture, not after, when the scale or height of the element is 0.5 or less and another alert if greater than 1.0.

Comment: @gomangomango than make sure to set a value to the `scale` variable. As far as I can see it's only being changed  on `case 'transform':` makes sense?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It is being set in case transform and case touch. But for some reason those are happening when the gesture ends, I want them to happen when the gesture is happening.

Comment: is that some external JS library? If yes, what they say about registering events values?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes, hammer.js. I don't know.

Comment: If _Hammer_ is not the famous _MC_ – then you should perhaps add a tag/link explaining what it actually is …

Comment: @CBroe http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/

Comment: than you should first see what they say before asking here. I hope this is what you're looking for: https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Instance-methods

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes, this is what I have done. I have used the .on method already. But how does that get the alerts to fire during the gesture?